# How to show which parent pom contains a plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

If my pom is a child a hierarchy of other poms, is there a way to show exactly which parent pom contains the definition of a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is most probably: No.

According to the way Maven builds its model before executing a certain build, the [Maven Builder Model](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.3/maven-model-builder/):

- In phase 1 the hierarchy of poms is resolved
- In phase 2 model normalization and plugins configurations are further resolved
- But only at the end of phase 2 the effective model validation is performed, which is done on the final effective `pom.xml` file, as a result of merges, overriding, profiling, injections (of properties) and so on.

To have a look at the full pom, the [`effective-pom`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) goal of the `maven-help-plugin` is definitely the right tool. It will show (or write to a given file) the final effective pom a build is gonna use.

The full definition of a plugin (its executions, its global configuration and so on) can only be created once we have the effective pom, because:

- the [`pluginManagement`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) section in any point in the hierarchy can influence a certain plugin
- The [`plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) section in any point in the hierarchy can also influnce it
- [`profiles`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) declared in any point in the hierarchy can also influence it
- [`properties`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties), if used as placeholders, can also play an important role

Having a look at the official [Maven POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html), we can see many entry point to influence a certain plugin definition, which will only be effective to our build once merged through the whole pom hierarchy. A definition per se would not help much since it can then be overriden/influenced further on on the hierarchy chain.

---

Think about the [`inherited`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) element of a `plugin`:

> `true` or `false`, whether or not this plugin configuration should apply to POMs which inherit from this one. Default value is `true`.

Or merging of `plugin` `configuration` sections:

> The default behavior is to merge the content of the configuration element according to element name. If the child POM has a particular element, that value becomes the effective value. if the child POM does not have an element, but the parent does, the parent value becomes the effective value.
>   You can control how child POMs inherit configuration from parent POMs by adding attributes to the children of the `configuration` element. The attributes are `combine.children` and `combine.self`. Use these attributes in a child POM to control how Maven combines plugin configuration from the parent with the explicit configuration in the child.

Or further down per `execution` of a `plugin`:

> `inherited`: Like the inherited element above, setting this `false` will supress Maven from passing this execution onto its children. This element is only meaningful to parent POMs.

The overall management can then be influenced by `pluginManagement`:

> Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way, except that rather than configuring plugin information for this particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one. However, this only configures plugins that are actually referenced within the plugins element in the children. The children have every right to override `pluginManagement` definitions.

As such, the plugin definition at a certain point of the pom hierarchy may not be meaningful to the final effective build.

Comment: Excellent explanation. From a practical point of view though, at least in my experience, the average inheritance chain is not that deep. Simply stepping through the hierarchy to find a particular plugin is not that hard. Sure, you would have to do it manually, but it shouldn't something that you do on a daily basis.